# XSL: Is matching by element the same as matching by element name?

Tags: xslt

I have been given an XSL file by my company to adapt for use by my department. In the file there are lines like the one below:

```
<xsl:template match="title | *[name() = 'title' or contains(@class, '/title ')]">
```

As far as I understood `match="title"` was the same as `match="*[name()='title']"`, which would make the initial `title` redundant. However, the file was originally written by a third party specializing in XML/XSL/HMTL development so I am assuming it is there for a reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There could be a difference if namespaces are involved. `name()` would return any namespace prefix in the XML. And `title` would only match `title` elements in no namespace, or in the namespace specified by `xpath-default-namespace` in the XSLT (if using XSLT 2.0).

Consider this contrived XML

```
<titles>
    <title id="1" />
    <title id="2" xmlns="test2" />
    <test3:title id="3" xmlns:test3="test3" />
</titles>
```

A template matching just `title` would only match the first one, but `*[name() = 'title']` would match the first two. So, in this case `title` is still redundant in your match.

However, in XSLT 2.0, you can use `xpath-default-namespace` in a stylesheet to specify a default namespace for unprefixed elements in an expression.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0" xpath-default-namespace="test3">
```

In this case, a template matching `title` would match the third `title` in the XML (`<test3:title id="3" xmlns:test3="test3" />`), but the template matching `*[name() = 'title']` would match the first two.

Note, there is also a `local-name()` which only returns the node name without any namespace prefix, so doing `*[local-name() = 'title']` would match all three `title` elements.